# How expensive is creating a BasePdpEngine in Authzforce Core?

Tags: authorization, xacml, authzforce

How often should I reuse this object? Always or is it fine to create a new one every authorization request? In terms of caching, do I cache the `BasePdpEngine` or my policy provider?

I am expecting a lot of authorization requests, so i'm not sure which optimization to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BasePdpEngine class is thread-safe, you can (and should!) reuse the same BasePdpEngine object to handle all requests. This is what we do in the [RESTful PDP](https://github.com/authzforce/restful-pdp) that handles XACML Requests via REST API.